# All information or All the information / oceans or the oceans

Tags: definite-article

Non native speakers are always confused about when to use the definite article.

All 1) the information I get from fish is used to manage 2) the oceans better.

I want to know how the two 'the' worked in the sentences.

How about the following sentence?

> All information I get from fish is used to manage oceans better.

Is the sentence completely wrong, or is this one different from the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

Both your examples, with and without the articles, are grammatically correct.

We use the definite article when referring to something *specific* that the audience is already aware of. It can also be used to refer to something previously mentioned.

'*The information*' refers to specific information. You don't have to use the article here, but you might want to use it if you have already referred to this information, or to infer that there is other information that you might gather that does not pertain to the subject under discussion.

'*The oceans*' could either refer to *all of the oceans of the world*, or, if you had previously mentioned a specific, limited set of oceans, it would refer back to the ones you already mentioned.

You could also use a third article and say "the fish", if you wanted to narrow the scope of the fish that you gather information from.

Answer (score 0):

*The information* refers to a specific set of information; that which the speaker obtains from fish.

*The oceans* refers to the oceans of the world.

*Fish* refers to fish in general.